# Proper use of transformers vs interceptors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

When POSTing to an endpoint in a service layer to update a user's profile, I need to strip certain values from the request payload (the profile with the desired modifications from the client) and re-attach them in the response payload (the updated profile from the server).  I am currently performing behavior using Angular's [request and response transformers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#transforming-requests-and-responses), like this:

```
myService.updateProfile = function (profile) {

    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        withCredentials: true,
        url: root + 'users/profile',
        data: profile,
        transformRequest : requestTransformer,
        transformResponse : responseTransformer
    });

};

// the map used during transformation below
var myMap = {
    0: 'foo', 
    1: 'bar',
    2: 'etc'
};

// prependTransform() and appendTransform() are similar to the example provided in Angular transformer docs here:
// https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#overriding-the-default-transformations-per-request
var requestTransformer = httpTransformer.prependTransform($http.defaults.transformRequest, function(profileRequest) {
    profileRequest.myKey = myMap.indexOf(profileRequest.myValue);
    delete profileRequest.myValue;

    return profileRequest;
});
var responseTransformer = httpTransformer.appendTransform($http.defaults.transformResponse, function(profileResponse) {
    profileRequest.myValue = myMap[profileRequest.myKey];
    delete profileRequest.myKey;

    return profileResponse;
});
```

I prepend a transformer to the default request transformers and append a transformer to the default response transformers.  My question is, is there a better way to do this?  Perhaps using [interceptors, as documented here,](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) instead?  If so, how?

Comment: I would just wrap the http request in a service. Basically, before the call, you strip it, then it comes back down, you can add it back in a .then call.

Comment: You can use interceptors but they're mostly helpful for intercepting HTTP requests/responses globally (meaning for each call made). You can still use interceptors but you have to determine the specific API route that only will be handled by your interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is fine but if you want an alternative, you can intercept specific requests like so. HTTP interceptors are mostly useful for handling global HTTP requests/responses (auth, error handling, etc.).

In any case, the "response" payload should be taken cared of from the API/server-side.

```
$provide.factory('userProfileInterceptor', function() {
  return {
    request: function(config) {
       if (config.url.indexOf('/users/profile') >=0){
           if (config.params.myValue) delete config.params.myValue;
       }
       return config;
    },
    response: function(response) {
       if (response.config.url.indexOf('/users/profile') >=0){
           delete response.data.myKey;
       }
       return response;
    }
  };
});

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('userProfileInterceptor');
```